# If statement inside elseif statement causing error

Tags: php, laravel

Okay, so I used to have this code and it worked fine:

```
    $lastpost   = ForumPos::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->orderby('created_at', 'desc')->first();

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
            return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                    ->withErrors($validator->messages());
    }
        elseif ($lastpost->created_at->diffInSeconds() < 15)
    {
            return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                    ->withErrors('You really need to slow down with your posting ;)');
    }
        else
    {
            $new_thread             = new ForumThr;
            $new_thread->topic      = $id;
            $new_thread->user_id    = Auth::id();
            $new_thread->title      = Input::get('title');
            $new_thread->save();

            $new_post               = new ForumPos;
            $new_post->thread       = $new_thread->id;
            $new_post->user_id      = Auth::id();
            $new_post->body         = Input::get('body');
            $new_post->save();

            return Redirect::to('/forum/thread/'.$new_thread->id.'');
    }
```

and this worked fine, until I noticed a little problem so I had to change this a bit to get this:

```
    $hasposted  = ForumPos::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->count();

    if ($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                    ->withErrors($validator->messages());
    } elseif ($hasposted != 0) {
        $last_post = ForumPos::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

        if ($last_post->created_at->diffInSeconds() < 15) {
            return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                    ->withErrors('You really need to slow down with your posting ;)');
        }
    } else {
            $new_thread             = new ForumThr;
            $new_thread->topic      = $id;
            $new_thread->user_id    = Auth::id();
            $new_thread->title      = Input::get('title');
            $new_thread->save();

            $new_post               = new ForumPos;
            $new_post->thread       = $new_thread->id;
            $new_post->user_id      = Auth::id();
            $new_post->body         = Input::get('body');
            $new_post->save();

            return Redirect::to('/forum/thread/'.$new_thread->id.'');
    }
```

Now when I post a thread and get to the if statement inside the elseif statement, I hit a roadblock. I get the following error:

[image: error #1]

I only get this error when I haven't specified the title variable in the controller so the view gets it, however there shouldn't be a view. Any ideas? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your `elseif` block (second condition)

```
if(...)
{
    //first condition
    return ...;
}
elseif ($hasposted != 0) {
{
    //second condition    
    $last_post = ForumPos::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

    if ($last_post->created_at->diffInSeconds() < 15) {
        return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                ->withErrors('You really need to slow down with your posting ;)');
    }
} 
else
{
    //third condition
    return ...;        
}
```

When your nested if statement fails

```
$last_post->created_at->diffInSeconds() < 15
```

this block finishes, and the rest of the conditional finishes without issuing a `Redirect`.  That is, your nested if statement knows nothing about the third conditional.  PHP/Laravel are doing what you told it to -- so tell it to do something else.

This is purely a style suggestion, but I've reached a point where I avoid multiple branch conditionals whenever possible, especially when returning from inside a branch.  A style more like

```
if(...)
{
    return Redirect();  //...
}

if(...)
{
    return Redirect();  //...
}

if(...)
{
    return Redirect();  //...
}

if(...)
{
    return Redirect();  //...
}
```

might look longer on the page, but it's much clearer what's going on.

```
If this?  Do something and go away (`return`)

Still here? Well if this-other-thing then do something and go away (`return`)

**Still** here? Well if this-other-thing then do something and go away (`return`)
```

You end up thinking in a series of yes/no tests, and avoid the very human/programmer problem you ran into with nested conditional logic.

Comment: I completely agree with your style recommendation. One note, you should always have a catch all return at the bottom of the method to return something in the case all the other ifs fail.

Answer (score 2):

In all your other conditions you do a redirect. If the elseif succeeds, but the if does not succeed then you do nothing. It is then trying to render a page using your master template but you have not set any of the variables that it needs. You could fix this by adding another redirect:

```
    if ($last_post->created_at->diffInSeconds() < 15) {
        return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                ->withErrors('You really need to slow down with your posting ;)');
    }
    else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('/somewhere/else/');
    }
```

Comment: Surely that wouldn't work? Surely it just moves on to the final else statement? That's what I need it to do anyway, I can't just redirect away.

Comment: No. It will only go into one of the branches of the top level if -> elseif -> else. You probably want to use an AND condition. Take a look at the other answer just posted. It is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After discussing this in the Laravel IRC room, we found the solution (and I believe answers here would have sufficed too)

In the end, I came up with this:

```
    $hasposted  = ForumPos::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->count();

    if ($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                    ->withErrors($validator->messages());
    } elseif ($hasposted != 0) {
        $last_post = ForumPos::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

        if ($last_post->created_at->diffInSeconds() < 15) {
            return Redirect::to('/forum/topic/'.$id.'/new')
                    ->withErrors('You really need to slow down with your posting ;)');
        }
    }

    $new_thread             = new ForumThr;
    $new_thread->topic      = $id;
    $new_thread->user_id    = Auth::id();
    $new_thread->title      = Input::get('title');
    $new_thread->save();

    $new_post               = new ForumPos;
    $new_post->thread       = $new_thread->id;
    $new_post->user_id      = Auth::id();
    $new_post->body         = Input::get('body');
    $new_post->save();

    return Redirect::to('/forum/thread/'.$new_thread->id.'');
```

If it passes all the if statements, it'll get through to the final request and now I'm happy to say it all works as planned. Thanks, lads!